# json.loads() - json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value

Tags: python, json

I should read a json file located in the same folder as the python file.
The code is this:

```
import json
import os

with open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'datasets.json'), 'r') as f:
    dataset = json.loads(f.read())
```

This is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Desktop/proj/ai/index.py", line 6, in <module>
    dataset = json.loads(f.read())
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 348, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 14 column 1 (char 284)
```

This is the JSON:

```
[
  {
    "name": "linear1",
    "values": [[1,3],[2,5],[3,7]]
  },
  {
    "name": "linear2",
    "values": [[1.1,2],[2.1,4.3],[2.9,6.4],[4.1,7.9],[5.2,9.7],[6.4,12],[6.5,13.3],[8,15.9],[8.9,18.1],[9.7,20.4]]
  },
  {
    "name": "parabolic1",
    "values": [[1,1],[2,4],[3,9]]
  },
]
```

Comment: We need the JSON to know what's wrong. You have a `JSONDecodeError`, we can't possibly determine the cause of that if we don't know the JSON being decoded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You JSON is incorrect,See where i have removed a comma in the JSON below

```
[
  {
    "name": "linear1",
    "values": [[1,3],[2,5],[3,7]]
  },
  {
    "name": "linear2",
    "values": [[1.1,2],[2.1,4.3],[2.9,6.4],[4.1,7.9],[5.2,9.7],[6.4,12],[6.5,13.3],[8,15.9],[8.9,18.1],[9.7,20.4]]
  },
  {
    "name": "parabolic1",
    "values": [[1,1],[2,4],[3,9]]
  }  < ---- Removed This Comma
]
```

Answer (score -1):

What is the contents of your json file? It is probably some incorrect formatting in there. There are various json validators online like https://jsonlint.com/ which can help check issues with these.

Comment: This isn't an answer.. use comments to provide suggestions that will improve the question.